# Why won't ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs work when the macro is running, but it does when it's not running?

Tags: vba, excel, io

The following **VBA** code is meant to run on **MS Office 2003**.  Because that's what our multi-billion dollar corporation gives us to work with.  =)

**The good news.**  It works perfectly if I'm editing code in the IDE and hit save.  Same if I'm working on the spreadsheet itself.  Creates a backup folder if none exists, and saves a dated backup copy in it.

**The bad news.**  When I run the main macro (too large to post), the code below executes but does not save a backup copy.  The event is called correctly.  In fact, it will create a backup folder if none exists.  Every line gets run.  The variables are all correct.  Error handling works.

**Simply put, ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs won't work if the main macros is running and calls ThisWorkbook.Save.**

I only learned VBA a couple months ago for this particular project, so apologies if there is something obvious.  However, I read all the relevant MSDN documentation and Googled like mad, but nothing came up.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

'********************************************************************
'Purpose:   Triggered by ThisWorkbook.BeforeSave event
'           Creates backup folder and saves date appended copies
'********************************************************************

    Dim strBackupPath As String         'Path to Backup Folder
    Dim strFarkPath As String           'Path to running workbook
    Dim strBackupName As String         'Filename of backup
    Dim strFullName As String           'Full path & filename of running workbook
    Dim strBackupExtension As String    'Extension of backup
    Dim strDestination As String        'Full path & filename of backup
    Dim strDrive As String              'Drive letter

    strFarkPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strDrive = Left(strFarkPath, 1)
    strBackupPath = strFarkPath & "\_Backups"
    strBackupName = "\Backup-" & Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now)
    strFullName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    strBackupExtension = Right(strFullName, Len(strFullName) - InStrRev(strFullName, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) + 1)
    strDestination = strBackupPath & strBackupName & strBackupExtension

    On Error GoTo Incorrect

    If Len(Dir(strBackupPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strBackupPath
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strDestination
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub

Incorrect:
    MsgBox "Unable to back record keeper up.  Next time, please run the program from a location where you can read and write files.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `SaveCopyAs` trigger the error handler, or just do nothing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If the macro is not running, it saves a copy when I hit Ctrl-S.  If the macro is running, it does nothing.  It does not trigger the error handler.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strDestination` before the save  - is the output what you expect?  (output should appear in the Immediate pane in the VB editor)

Comment: Yes, the output is what I expected.  I've stared at that variable for some time, wondering if I was crazy.  Then, I reminded myself that it works perfectly if I'm editing and hit Ctrl-S.

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are there other workbooks open when you're running this code?  Your code references `ActiveWorkbook`, which is not necessarily the same as `ThisWorkbook` if other workbooks are open...

Comment: Thanks for trying it out.  Generally, no, there wouldn't be other workbooks.  Even if there were, the main macro makes "ThisWorkbook" the "ActiveWorkbook," so I can't see how that would affect it.  Did you by any chance run a different macro that called ThisWorkbook.Save to see if that made a difference?  I just can't figure what would be capable of preventing it from saving, regardless...

Comment: Well, I thought I had tried that, but on retrying it didn't work.  It *does* work if you use the `Workbook_AfterSave` event though.  There are a bunch of other posts out there describing this problem, but no real solutions.

Comment: Really?  I tried to find them.  Thanks so much for letting me know.  Could you possibly help me determine whether 2003 has Workbook_AfterSave?  I wrote this using 2010 in some kind of compatibility mode, but when I ran it on 2003, it didn't seem to recognize the event.  I tried MSDN docs, but couldn't tell for sure.  If 2003 doesn't have it, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't know - AfterSave wasn't even there in Excel2007...  Untested, but as a workaround instead of using SaveCopyAs try calling ThisWorkbook.Save and then create a copy of the saved file under the "backup" filename.  You may need to turn off events while you do this to prevent re-entering your beforesave Sub.  I will try it out...

Comment: Yes, I tried that workaround.  The difficulty is that I can't rely on having MS Scripting (for FSO, etc.) and the built-in VBA copy command won't work on open workbooks.  Do you know of another way?

Comment: Posted my answer before seeing your comment - you could use an API call or MS-DOS (!) to create the copy.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172711

Comment: looks like your excel has no time to execute all commands, so maybe add a doevents before (or after) the save attemp.

Comment: is it my imagination or would a save inside before_save relaunch (in loops) itself ? i'd add a `application.enableevents=false` before that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the last part of your existing sub, modified to create a copy.
Note you cannot use the built-in `FileCopy` to make the copy (you'll get "Permission Denied")

```
    On Error GoTo Incorrect

    If Len(Dir(strBackupPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strBackupPath
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").copyfile _
                     ThisWorkbook.FullName, strDestination

    Application.EnableEvents = True '<<<<

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub

Incorrect:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'never leave this False!
    MsgBox "Unable to back record keeper up.  Next time, please run the program from a location where you can read and write files.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance.  My "real job" has kept me from this for a few weeks.  Appreciate it!